# C# ThrowIfCancellationRequested() not catch properly

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have a long executing function within a class, with progress indicator and cancel possibility. I end up with this code

```
static class Class1
{
    public static async Task<int> MyLongFunction(IProgress<int> progress, CancellationToken ct)
    {

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                if (progress != null)
                {
                    progress.Report(i);
                }

            }

        });

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Now on the main Form, I end up with this:

```
void ReportProgress(int value)
{
    //Update the UI to reflect the progress value that is passed back.
    pb.Value = value;
}

private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started");

    var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        int test = await Class1.MyLongFunction(progressIndicator, cts.Token);
        Console.WriteLine("After long task");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        //Do stuff to handle cancellation
        Console.WriteLine("Lonk task cancelled: "+ex.Message);
    }

}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cts.Cancel();
    Console.WriteLine("Task cancellation requested.");

}
```

The code works, but within the IDE (VS2015) it will always hang on this line

```
ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

saying that

*An exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The operation was cancelled.*

But I used try/catch block to catch this!
If I continue execution, indeed is catch as supposed.

This is the output:

```
Started
Task cancellation requested.
Lonk task cancelled: The operation was cancelled.
```

So why the IDE stops saying that I was not handling it?

Thank you in advance,

EDITED
After @Chris Barber answer, I disabled that "Break when thrown" but still get stopped in the same point, see this image

[image]

Comment: Isn't the IDE meant to stop when an exception is thrown? Can't you just F5 and continue the debugger?

Comment: @SouXin Any exception thrown in the delegate executed by `Task.Run` gets caught and wrapped in the returned task, which means the exception will be rethrown by the `await`. Assuming the context is properly captured by the `await`, the exception will get thrown on the right thread.

Comment: So, the key detail here is "If I continue execution, indeed is catch as supposed." Here's a riddle: if the exception really wasn't handled, could you continue execution?

Comment: YES, I did the test without IDE and exception get cought properly, at least nothing crashes, etc. So basically just IDE stops telling me that there is a exception not handled, but if I press F5 (continue) in debugger, I will arrive in the catch as supposed. So why IDE stops?

Comment: Have you tried to uncheck the checkbox shown in your screenshot?

Comment: yes, but I was confused by disabling from table above and nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected in Visual Studio, by default it will break when all exceptions are thrown.

You can control which exceptions it should break for in the Exceptions Settings window.

Microsoft have some documentation about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)

In your case, if you untick System.OperationCanceledException (or all of the Common Language Runtime Exceptions) it won't break when the exception is thrown.